# 1 материал на несколько объектов с разным свойством

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Подскажите, как можно реализовать 1 материал на несколько объектов, которые отличаются лишь цветом?
**Пытался:** `MaterialPropertyBlock` - создался 1 общий материал.

```
public GameObject prefab;

public GameObject[] cubes= new GameObject[3];

void Awake()
{
    block = new MaterialPropertyBlock ();

}
void Start () {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cubes[i]=Instantiate (prefab, new Vector3 (i, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        if (i == 0) {
            color = new Color (1, 1, 1);
        } else if (i == 1) {
            color = new Color (1, 0, 1);
        } else {
            color = new Color (0, 0, 1);
        }

        Renderer _renderer = cubes [i].GetComponent<Renderer> ();
        //_renderer.GetPropertyBlock(block);
        block.SetColor("_Color", color);
        _renderer.SetPropertyBlock(block);
    }
}
```

**В итоге:** используется 1 общий материал, цвет у каждого объекта разный, но используется кол-во `draw call` такое же, как и создание материала для каждого объекта (на объект по `draw call`), в материале стоит в шейдере `[PreRendererData]`.
Каким образом можно уменьшить `draw call`, если на сцене у меня 50 объектов с материалом отличающимся только цветом?

Comment: У вас все равно создалось 50 материалов. Только использовать инстансинг gpu( если система поддерживвет).

Comment: И он не помогает,ничего не меняется.Создать материалы со всеми цветами не вариант(так как цвет на объектах не повторяется)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html Все расписано подробно.(читать нужно именно для новой версии,для старых версий хуже док). 
P.S.Не работает с Canvas Renderer